# Xamarin.Forms properties are not saved in Release on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, properties, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and Application.Current.Properties to persist user settings. I'm testing it on Android and it works fine

- in Debug mode
- in Release mode with linker configuration set to **None**

But it doesn't work with linker configuration set to **SDK Assemblies Only**. 
I'm testing by deploying an APK file directly to the device. Then I try to enter some settings and restart the application - and after restart all settings are lost. I'm not using complex data types, only *string* and *bool*.

I've found a workaround suggested here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30723/problems-with-application-current-properties.
It suggests to ignore Xamarin.Forms.Core assembly, but it doesn't help.

When linker configuration is set to **None**, the APK size is huge (50mb!). I want to avoid that.

How can I persist application properties in Release build without setting linker configuration to None? Is it a known Xamarin bug?

Comment: What are you storing, because it could be swallowing an exception while saving.

Comment: Are you testing this by repeatedly deploying the app from the IDE?  If so, you may be overwriting the saved data each time.  For Android there is an option to preserve app data when deploying.

Comment: Did u find out any solution / workaround?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, from xamarin docs(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary) :

> Note: the Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for storage. Attempting to store other types (such as List can fail silently).

If you want to store non-primitive type, you can, for example, convert it into JSON string using Newtonsoft.Json serializer, and then write to Properties(dont forget to deserialze when you read from Properties)

---

Btw, there is know bug: Properties didnt work in Release mode on Android.
Suggest using [Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings), it works pretty well.

Comment: The OP has stated (possibly as an edit after your answer) that they are saving only primitives.  (y)